# Does graph Cartesian product distribute over graph join?

Tags: graph-theory

I've been trying to construct a ring using finite graphs. I've considered a number of options, and graph join (or the simpler graph union) seem to make sense for addition. Cartesian product seems to make sense for multiplication, but I'm not sure. Obviously multiplication has to distribute over addition. I can't tell if it does in this case (I'm assuming two graphs are equal if they're isomorphic of course).

I should be able to figure this point out on my own, but I'm so rusty at this point, that I just can't. If anyone has a nice app that can calculate join and product for graphs, it might be easy to find a counter example.

Comment: neither operation distributes over the other, also, for graphs the term isomorphic is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G+(H_1 \square H_2)$ has $|G| + |H_1||H_2|$ vertices while $(G+H_1)\square (G+H_2)$ has $(|G|+|H_1|)(|G|+|H_2|)$ vertices.

The other distribution also doesn't hold.

In  $G\square (H_1+H_2)$  $(g,h) \sim (g',h')$ never holds when $g$ and $g'$ are distinct non-adjacent vertices.

In $(G\square H_1) + (G\square H_2)$ we have $(g,h) \sim (g,h')$ always holds if $h\in H_1$ and $h'\in H_2$.

In particular if $G,H_1$ and $H_2$ are graphs with no edges on $n,m_1$ and $m_2$ vertices then  $G\square (H_1+H_2)$  $(g,h) \sim (g',h')$ will be isomorphic to $n$ copies of $K_{m_1,m_2}$ and  $(G\square H_1) + (G\square H_2)$ will be isomorphic to $K_{nm_1,nm_2}$

Comment: Does the issue exist in straight graph union as well?

Comment: Actually, using similar logic, I think I can answer that question myself. Let me think about it.

Comment: Actually... it's harder to figure out for union.

Comment: you want to see if cartesian product ditributes over union?

Comment: Correct. Assume that when performing the union of G + G it's considered two separate sets of vertices.

Comment: I like to represent the union as $G\oplus H$

Comment: So you want to check if $G\square(H_1 \oplus H_2)$ is isomorphic to $(G\square H_1 )\oplus (G\square H_2)$, You can assume two edges are adjacent in the first graph and check if it also happens in the second graph, and viceversa

Comment: Hopefully it is. Otherwise I have to go back to searching for other graph operations.

Comment: it is, the strategy described above works, there are a couple of cases that need to be considered.

Comment: I proved the result by cases. I'm still curious, are there any graph products which distribute over graph join?

Comment: Thanks again for the help, @yorch. Managed to find another set of operations that do work as well. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353325239_Studying_Natural_Graphs

Comment: great stuff ! :)